# Trying to use docker-compose but unknown error happens

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, nano, portainer

I am trying to install traggo docker. I have the latest docker and latest docker CE installed.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
services:
  traggo:
    image: traggo/server:latest
    ports:
      - 3030:3030
    environment:
      TRAGGO_DEFAULT_USER_NAME: "admin"
      TRAGGO_DEFAULT_USER_PASS: "mynewpassword"
    volumes:
      - ./traggodata:/opt/traggo/data
```

When I try to run the `docker-compose up -d` command, I get following errors. I have never seen these errors before:

```
mead650@mead650-vm:~/docker/traggo$ sudo docker-compose up -d && docker-compose logs -f
Creating traggo_traggo_1 ... done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 704, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 399, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 30, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 786, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 718, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 704, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 399, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 30, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
    return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 645, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 501, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.29.2', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
    command_func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 60, in project_from_options
    return get_project(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 152, in get_project
    client = get_client(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
    client = docker_client(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
    client = APIClient(use_ssh_client=not use_paramiko_ssh, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

I tried traggo's directions, and they do not have the help or Google search. I have two machines with docker and protainor installed. I have Ubuntu Server, the latest version. I never have issues with using docker-compose from the ether of these machines.

Comment: First, don't do sudo with docker compose. Looks like linux, right? Is this WSL2 or "plain" Linux? How did you install docker?

Comment: Also, what does `docker info` show?